# Custom Extension Methods causing build error when attempting to launch the debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using my own Extension Methods throughout several of my projects.  When I compile(Build/Rebuild) all is fine.  However when I start the debugger and the code recompiles, I get a list of errors all associated with the extension methods stating that they aren't a member of the class they are attached to.  Any thoughts on why this might be happening?  It seems intermittent as I can recompile and clean and recompile several times and it finally will allow me to launch the debugger.

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: Can you paste a bit of your extension method code (just stubs) and the exact VS error?

Comment: It says "[Extension Method] is not a member of [Class being extended]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the PDB's are not being generated properly? Are you launching from VS or attaching to a process? If attaching, make sure the PDB's are in the same location as the application.

Try: 
Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced
Set 'Debug Info' = Full

Also, what namespace do you have the extension methods in? Make sure they are in the ROOT namespace or just remove the namespace all together (just for now as a test).

What kind of types are you extended? Is it possible you have two types of the same name and you're trying to extend the wrong one?

Comment: I'm launching from inside Visual Studio.  Starting a new instance of the debugger for a web project.

Comment: are extension methods in a different project? If so, rebuild each project one by one and try again.

Comment: Yes they live in a different project.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to check all of your configurations and make sure they are set to debug or release. If it builds, it should run too. If this is an executable, do a build then execute it and then attach to the process or just add Debugger.Launch() in the start of the code and see what happens.