# Extension Method is not a member of Class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

For some time now I have been using extension methods to expand the functionality of already existing classes. An example:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub DrawRoundedRectangle(graphics As Graphics, pen As Pen, x As Single, y As Single, width As Single, height As Single, radius As Single)
    graphics.DrawRoundedRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height, radius, RectangleEdgeFilter.All)
End Sub
```

This happily extends the graphics object so that I can call: `e.graphics.DrawRoundedRectangle()`

However every so often Visual Studio will report:

> DrawRoundedRectangle is not a member of System.Drawing.Graphics

This means that I am unable to build due to the errors, and as of yet other than restarting Visual Studio (time consuming) I am yet to find a way to overcome these errors.

I have numerous extension methods (currently around 10) on various different classes, all of which fall over at the same time, this generates 66 errors.

My question is, Is there anything I am missing whilst creating these extension methods, or is there anything that can be done to stop these errors occuring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Extension Methods causing build error when attempting to launch the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853977/custom-extension-methods-causing-build-error-when-attempting-to-launch-the-debug)

Comment: I've run into the same issue with resolution.  It *seems* to be related to 32-bit systems and since switching to 64-bit I've not had the issue.  Restarting always clears up the problem.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543198/vb-net-project-with-extensions-methods-generates-errors

Answer (score 7):

Do you define the extensions in a Public Module?
Tried to 'rebuild solution', does it fix the issue?

Comment: It would fix the issue, very temporarily, only to return 5-10 minutes later. Was very time consuming. Recently upgraded to VS2012 and this issue no longer occurs.