# VB.NET DataRow Extension Method in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq

We currently use a number of extension methods in our C# application for converting a generic dataset to a strongly-typed object using LINQ. The main purpose is that the extension method can log an error if there is some casting type issue or other exception.

We are trying to convert this code to VB.NET application but the Module to expose an extension method to the DataRow object doesn't work. It doesn't compile. The following line in snippet 2 has a compile error, it doesn't see GetFieldAsString.

```
.MajorPurchaseXID = row.GetFieldAsString("") _
```

Here is the code in c# that works, first snippet is the extension method located in our linq class. The second snippet is the usage of this extension method in our data access layer method.

```
public static class Linq
{
    public static string GetFieldAsString(this DataRow row, string field)
    {
        return row.Field<string>(field);
    }
}
```

2nd Snippet >>

```
List<OfferGroupInfo> offerGroupList = new List<OfferGroupInfo>();
offerGroupList = (from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                               select new OfferGroupInfo
                               {
                                   XID = row.GetFieldAsInt("OfferGroupXID"),
                                   OfferGroupTypeXID = row.GetFieldAsInt("OfferGroupTypeXID"),
                                   OfferGroupType = row.GetFieldAsString("OfferGroupType"),
                                   Name = row.GetFieldAsString("OfferGroup"),
                                   Description = row.GetFieldAsString("OfferGroupDesc")
                               }).ToList();
```

Now, here is our conversion to vb.net. The first snippet is the module with the method marked as an extension. The second snippet is the usage, again in our data access.

We have tried several things but can't get the GetFieldAsString method to work as an extension of DataRow object as it is in C#. We need to get this working as we want to call row.>ExtensionMethodName> versus something like (datarow, field, etc...) as parameters. Thoughts?

```
Namespace ToolBox
    Module LinqExtensionMethods

      <Extension()>
      Public Function GetFieldAsString(row As DataRow, field as String) As String
        Try
            Return row.Field(Of String)(field)
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogHandler.WriteError("some error message here")
            Throw New HandledException
        End Try
      End Function

    End Module
End Namespace
```

2nd Snippet >>

```
Dim mppTicketTermList As New List(Of MPPTicketTerms)
mppTicketTermList = (From row In ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                                 Select New MPPTicketTerms With _
                                 { _
                                     .MajorPurchaseXID = row.GetFieldAsString("") _
                                 }).ToList()
```

Comment: Please tell us what the problem is.  Just saying it doesn't work does not help at all.  Your catch block seems to throw away all information about any exceptions that might have been thrown.  Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: We can't get the GetFieldAsString method to work as an extension of DataRow. The GetFieldAsString function call in the line: .MajorPurchaseXID = row.GetFieldAsString("") does not compile as it doesn't see it. The Module class to expose an extension method to the DataRow object doesn't seem to work. It doesn't show up in intellisense and doesn't compile.

Comment: You're code seems legit you're prolly missing an import clause for ToolBox or ComplierServices

Comment: Then what's the compiler error?

Comment: sdf - no, we have import clause for ToolBox and import to compilerservices is not needed on the calling method class, just where the module is created.

Comment: dunaway - compile error is "GetFieldAsString" is not a member of "System.Data.DataRow". As I stated, extension method inside the module is not exposed to the calling method's DataRow object. It doesn't see it. The module and calling method's class have different namespaces but all imports and references are accurate as we have many other classes in Toolbox which have worked just fine for years, no issue there.

Comment: If all your imports are correct the code should be okay. Check if you're not a victim of the bug in this question(connect article inside) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564735/extension-method-is-not-a-member-of-class

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue, the Module should be changed to Public Module and everything works fine then. Oops, what a pain!